# Fedora Linux KDE Installer Is Invisible

Tags: linux, installation, fedora

Ive tried to google about, asked on several discord servers tried adding nomodeset etc on the kernel boot options but nothing seems to work.

The problem is that when i boot into the fedora kde live enviroment from my USB and open the installer it creates another layer of a desktop where i cant click, its just invisible, i have verified the checksum for the ISO, can anyone help?

My PC Specs:

Os: Kubuntu
i5 6400
Nvidia GTX 1050 Ti
8GB Ram
1TB HDD